# Unable to "Start a new Android project" in Android Studio 3.0.1 (Ubuntu 17.10 x64)

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu, ubuntu-17.10

I Just update my Android Studio from version 2.3 to 3.0.1. The update **runs successfully without error** (I use new configuration and leave old configuration, I also update the SDK too).

But unfortunately, After these update **I unable to start a new android project** (There's no response when I click on "Start a new Android Studio Project"). I stuck in this screen:
[image: There's no response when I click on "Start a new Android Studio Project"]

Then, I try to fresh install, but I still can't "Start a new Android Studio Project". 
If I "**Open an existing Android Studio Project**" it's good, **there's no problem**.

Any idea or solution for this problem?

[ More information ]

OS: Linux Ubuntu 17.10 LXDE Desktop

Java: openjdk1.8

Answer (score 0):

Can't Identify the problem but for a temporary solution need to start a new project means Kindly open existing project and after click File-->New project to start a new project.